# How to Preview Uploaded Image File From File Input with Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, dropzone

I am using a plugin called [dropzone](https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/) which leaves rendering the image pretty much how to the user.

so I have done this

```
  <Dropzone
      onDrop={this.handleDropChange}}>
      <p>
        Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
      </p>
    </Dropzone>



 @observable files = [];
  @action
  handleDropChange = (files) => {
    
    files.forEach(file => {
        this.loadFile(file);
    });
}

  @action
  loadFile(file){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener('load',() => {
        runInAction(() => {
            this.files.push({file: file, preview: reader.result,  uploaded: false})
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(reader.result);
          });
      },false);

    // reader.readAsDataURL(file.fileObject);
  }

      <img src={this.props.preview} />
```

Problem is though when I drag in say 500 images it takes awhile for them to render on the screen. I think reactjs is having a hard time as it is essentially re-rendering 500 times since each "file reader load" causes a new item to be put into the files array.

Is there away to batch this or first do all the loading then re-render?

Answer (score 1):

`revokeObjectURL` is for object url's and not meant for other strings|urls|base64.
You can create a objectURL by calling `URL.createObjectURL` like so:

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(file || blob)
var image = new Image()
image.src = url
document.body.appendChild(image)
```

There is no need to use FileReader and read all the content encode it as base64 then let the browser decode it back into binary. that is a waste of resource...

revoking the objecturl should be done when you no longer need the url

Comment: if they go to a new page(SPA) will the resources from the createObjectUrl still need to be disposed of?

Comment: Especially if the page is a SPA, otherwise not so much as it will be revoked when you leave the page

Comment: So how do I manage it then. I thought if I create it then release it that would statsify it. Otherwise I got to do it after they leave that component which would also mean I would have to keep a reference to it.

Comment: You could do it as soon as the image is loaded `img.onload = () => URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src)`